# Multi-Row PL/SQL Select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been performing queries for awhile using Excel VBA and other tools, but I am trying to transition to be able to perform some tasks directly in SQL and PL/SQL.  I have been trying to create PL/SQL that will perform the following SELECT and have just not been able to grasp what I'm reading.

```
SELECT
  c.NAME, i.PROPERTY
FROM
  Schema.Table1 c,  Schema.Table2 i
WHERE
  c.ID = i.Prop_ID
  AND c.NAME = 'XXXX'
```

I want to be able to output the name, property.
I have a couple of restrictions.  First, I cannot make any changes to the database.  Second I will running this select across a number of identical schema.

Last any recommendations for a good PL/SQL reference would also be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure? There is no PL/SQL in your example

Comment: I need to create a script I can run on different databases.  I have tried it directly in SQL, but the schema names are dynamic.  I can perform some of these things with Execute Immediate Selects with dynamic SQL.  I have just not been able to figure out how to process multiple rows returned by the select statement.

Comment: What do you mean "process multiple rows"? See [this](https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Execute-Immediate-and-Cursors,4)

Comment: Are you trying to build a SQL*Plus script?  Displaying data is generally something that the client is responsible for.  You can write a stored function that takes a schema name as a parameter, uses dynamic SQL to construct the SQL statement, and returns a `sys_refcursor`.  But then the client application would need to know how to call this function in a loop and how to fetch the data from the cursor and display it to a human.  SQL and PL/SQL run only on the server, what is running on the client that would do this display?

Comment: Yes I'm building a SQL*Plus script.  I'm querying the database of an existing application which is why I cannot do anything that modifies the database.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to run the SQL*Plus scripts with substitution variables.  These allow us to inject values each time we run the script.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#CACIFHGB).

```
SELECT
  c.NAME, i.PROPERTY
FROM
  &&Target_Schema..Table1 c
    ,  &&Target_Schema..Table2 i
WHERE
  c.ID = i.Prop_ID
  AND c.NAME = 'XXXX'
/
```

Couple of notes:

1. The '&&' notation means you only need to enter the schema name once.  If you want to run the script against a different schema in the same session you will need to `undef target_schema`.
2. The two `..` after the schema is not a typo.  It is a quirk of passing schema as a substitution variable that we need to escape the dot notation.

Comment: I will give it a shot, but I need to execute this select across many schema (100+).